# Split string from time

Tags: java, split

I am getting time as like follow.

```
" Time : 06:00:00 AM "
```

I have used split method as follows, `split(":")`. Then it split time from all the `":"` in string.

I want to separate time just after first `":"` and remove the `"AM"` fraction from then time.

Please can anybody help me with this code.

I have build this simple sample as follows. My effort to split data after ":". Above problem occurs when it is come to split time.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class StringBuilderSample {
    public static void main(String []arg) {
        List<Object> dataList = new ArrayList<Object>();
        Object[] dataArr = {
                "Serial no : 10",
                "Supplier ID : 1",
                "Supplier Name : Md40",
                "GRN no : 20555",
                "Bag ID : 10",
                "Weight : 500",
                "Date : 09-10-2017",
                "Time : 16:09 PM",
                "User ID : 204"
        };
        for(int j=0;j<dataArr.length;j++) {
            String arrayData = dataArr[j].toString();
            Object[] fraction = arrayData.split(":");
            if(fraction.length>2) {
                StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                for(int i=1; i<fraction.length;i++) {
                    strBuilder.append(fraction[i]);
                }
                String newString = strBuilder.toString();
                dataList.add(newString);
            }else {
                dataList.add(fraction[1]);
            }
        }
        for(Object data : dataList) {
            System.out.println(data);
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: What language/tool are you using?

Comment: I am doing this with java.

Comment: I edited the code again for more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the limit parameter of split method:

```
Object[] fraction = arrayData.split(":", 2);
```

this will give:

```
fraction[0] --> Time 
fraction[1] --> 16:09 PM
```

Comment: Thank you very much Toto. Your suggestion solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is to split the string "Serial no : 10" to "10" for all the objects and the time has ":" and which is causing you trouble then you can try the below code

```
    for(int j=0;j<dataArr.length;j++) {
        String arrayData = dataArr[j].toString();
        String fraction = arrayData.substring(arrayData.indexOf(":") + 1);
        dataList.add(fraction);
    }
    for(Object data : dataList) {
        System.out.println(data);
    }
```